# Nested tree Structure Data Generation

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, lodash, angular6

please bare with my English and writing question, i have a array of json data which i am trying to make it in a nested tree structure but not getting success , hope someone can help me out.
My Example Data:

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Abc",
  "path" : "/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Xyz",
  "path" : "/Abc/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Pqr",
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 4,
  "name" : "Zap", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
  "type" : "folder"
 },{
  "id" : 5,
  "name" : "file1", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
  "type" : "file"
},{
  "id" : 6,
  "name" : "file2", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
  "type" : "file"
},{
  "id" : 7,
  "name" : "file3", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
  "type" : "file"
},{
  "id" : 8,
  "name" : "file4", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/Zap/",
  "type" : "file"
}
```

Sorry i am taking little big data to make understand properly, now the nested format i which i want it is something like this.

```
[{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Abc",
  "path" : "/",
  "type" : "folder"
  "Children":[{
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Xyz",
    "path" : "/Abc/",
    "type" : "folder",
    "Children":[{
           "id" : 3,
           "name" : "Pqr",
           "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
           "type" : "folder",
           "Children": [{
                   "id" : 4,
                    "name" : "Zap", 
                    "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
                    "type" : "folder",
                    "Children":[{
                            "id" : 8,
                             "name" : "file4", 
                              "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/Zap/",
                             "type" : "file"
                         }]
                   },{
                    "id" : 5,
                    "name" : "file1", 
                    "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
                    "type" : "file"
                   },{
                      "id" : 6,
                      "name" : "file2", 
                      "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
                      "type" : "file"
             }]
         },{
           "id" : 7,
           "name" : "file3", 
           "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/", 
           "type" : "file"
      }]
 }]
 }
```

Now the login  using with lodash is like this: datas = allData

```
 const dd= [];
_.forEach(datas, function(v, k) {
  let cc = {};
    if (v.type == 'folder') {

      cc['children'] = _.filter(datas, function(v1, k1) {
        if (v.path + v.name + '/' == v1.path || v1.path.startsWith(v.path + v.name + '/')) {
          return v1;
        }
      });
      cc['name'] = v.name;
      cc['type'] = v.type;
      cc['id'] = v.id;
      cc['path'] = v.path;
      dd.push(cc);
    } else {
      if (v.path == '/') {
        dd.push(cc);
      }
    }

});
```

But not getting it properly, i know question got too long but help me out with this.

Comment: it is consistent know? it always have id, path, name, type and children if there are some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew! That was fun.

```
const data = [ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Abc",
  "path" : "/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Xyz",
  "path" : "/Abc/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Pqr",
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 4,
  "name" : "Zap", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
  "type" : "folder"
 },{
  "id" : 5,
  "name" : "file1", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
  "type" : "file"
},{
  "id" : 6,
  "name" : "file2", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/",
  "type" : "file"
},{
  "id" : 7,
  "name" : "file3", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
  "type" : "file"
},{
  "id" : 8,
  "name" : "file4", 
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/Pqr/Zap/",
  "type" : "file"
}]

const pathPartRegex = /.*?\//g;
const tree = _.reduce(data, (result, value) => {
    const pathParts = value.path.match(pathPartRegex);
    let node = result;
    let path = "";

    // Go down through tree until last path part
    const notLastPart = pathParts.splice(0, pathParts.length - 1);
    for (const pathPart of notLastPart) {
        path += pathPart;
        const existingNode = node.children 
                                ? node.children.find(item => item.path === path)
                                : node.find(item => item.path === path);
        if (existingNode) {
            node = existingNode
        } else {
            // If we need to traverse over a path that doesn't exist, just create it
            // See notes 
            const newNode = {
                path: path,
                children: []
            };

            // The root element is just an array, and doesn't have a children property
            if (node.children) {
                node.children.push(newNode);
            } else {
                node.push(newNode);
            }
            node = newNode;
        }
    }

    // Add new node
    const newNode = {
        id: value.id,
        name: value.name,
        type: value.type,
        path: value.path,
        children: []
    };

    // The root element is just an array, and doesn't have a children property
    if (node.children) {
        node.children.push(newNode);
    } else {
        node.push(newNode);
    }

    return result;
}, []);
```

---

Tested via RunKit (https://npm.runkit.com/lodash)

---

Notes:

The sample data set does not cover how to handle a situation where the "parent" path is not defined at all:

```
const data = [{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Abc",
  "path" : "/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Pqr",
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
  "type" : "folder"
}];
```

Nor a situation where the "parent" path is defined after the child:

```
const data = [{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Abc",
  "path" : "/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Pqr",
  "path" : "/Abc/Xyz/",
  "type" : "folder"
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Xyz",
  "path" : "/Abc/",
  "type" : "folder"
}];
```

The code I wrote will handle these, but may create nodes without an `id` property. If you need to handle situations like that, you can either fix the input data beforehand or modify this code to handle those situations.

Comment: yo really a nice answer just one question at end you are returning result but your are not assigning anything to result than how it is getting updated every time?

Comment: and i also got one solution sharing at below.

Comment: @user3458271 Essentially, that's just how reduce works. It starts with an initial value of an empty array (third argument) and the value returned from each iteration is passed to the next

Answer (score 1):

The answer which i also got working is something like this:

```
const sts=_.memoize(function(){ return []; });
const result = _.filter(folderdata, function(item){
  let parentName = '';
  if(item.path != '/')parentName = item.path;
  item.children = sts(item.path+item.name+'/');
  if (item.type == 'folder') return !(parentName && sts(parentName).push(item));
});
```